# SQL Query Help 1 to N

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with a 1 to N relation in there.

```
    Sample Data:
    Table User:
    ID,Name
    Table Entry:
    ID,Name 
    Table User_Entry:
    UserID,EntryID
```

I would like to get all Entries (their ID and NAME) and a flag, that states, if a User with ID x has this Entry (via Table USER_ENTRY)

Comment: better give your sample data.

Comment: and the queries you tried

Comment: you can update your question, we see nothing in comments

Comment: Sorry, now I updated it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to select from your entry table to get all your entries, and then left join to your user_entry table to find out if a particular user has that entry:

```
SELECT  e.ID, 
        e.Name,
        CASE WHEN ue.EntryID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS UserFlag
FROM    Entry AS e
        LEFT JOIN user_Entry AS ue
            ON ue.EntryID = e.ID
            AND ue.UserID = x
```

Answer (score 1):

@GarethD answer is fine but I would go one step further to verify that actual `UserID` in `User_Entry` is actual valid user in `User` table. If you do not have foreign keys on the table it is possible that you have `UserID` that does not exists in `User` table. To enforce that check you can join both tables and verify `Id` from `User` table in the following manner.

```
SELECT e.EntryID
       ,e.NAME
       ,CASE WHEN u.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 AS UserFlag
    FROM Entry AS e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Entry AS ue
        ON e.id = ue.EntryID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN User AS u
        ON ue.UserID = u.ID
```

To go even further you can write case statement to can find bad records by checking both `UserID` in `User_Entry` table and checking `ID` in `User` table.

```
SELECT e.EntryID
       ,e.NAME
       ,CASE WHEN u.ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 AS UserFlag
       ,CASE WHEN ue.UserId IS NOT NULL AND u.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS InvalidUserID
    FROM Entry AS e
    LEFT OUTER JOIN User_Entry AS ue
        ON e.id = ue.EntryID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN User AS u
        ON ue.UserID = u.ID
```

Answer (score -3):

You actually don't need Table C to link the ID's together.  This is exactly what a [SQL JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is for!  Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table_a JOIN table_b WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id
```

Comment: -1 wrong syntax and query, without knowing what the OP actually wants

Comment: -1 If you write the sample you should at least specify right syntax. Also read this [Discouraging w3schools as a resource](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87678/discouraging-w3schools-as-a-resource) and  [Will I be downvoted for giving a W3Schools link?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120025/will-i-be-downvoted-for-giving-a-w3schools-link)

Comment: You people turn this into a community where it's frustrating to give or receive help because if we don't ask or provide help in the right way (as determined by an arbitrary set of people, like those who don't like W3 Schools), we get down-voted.  Down-voting others because you don't like W3 Schools or because the OP's question is unclear doesn't actually make your reputation any better even though it might make you feel special.

Comment: @jkovba I did not downvote for linking W3School, it came purely from incorrect syntax. If you are unsure on syntax you should verify it. if you already answered with wrong syntax and someone told you it is wrong. Just update your answer with right syntax and people will be happy to upvote your answer. I think everyone goes through stage of frustration on this site when their answers are downvoted. To provide good answers read [Jon Skeet's blog](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx). In regards to W3School read www.w3fools.com